# Need to FTP windows server without user access

Tags: windows, unix, command-line, ftp, automation

I am able to access the server ftp:// 172.155.58.78/Util in browser where my reports are present. I am able to right click and download them.

However I want to automate the FTP of these report files. So I tried to FTP through CMD prompt, this is asking me for the user/pass which I do not have.

Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser probably supplies the FTP server with the default anonymous account credentials, without you knowing it.

Try to login from your cmd with username anonymous and no password, or use your e-mail address as your password.